# Realtime HLS file playback with nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, video, streaming, http-live-streaming

I have built a php crud app that allows users to upload videos and queue them for conversion where I use FFMPEG to convert them to M3U8 Playlist format. I now need to build a streaming server that will allow me to playback those files in realtime so that when a user browses to the page they see the video playing at its current time. I know that nodejs has streaming capabilities and have done a great amount of research on video streaming and am coming up short. Can someone point me in the right direction with this. I have a concept in mind by using web sockets but I can't find an example that will help me solve my problem.

Comment: The following should be useful as it is open source and should do what you want, or provide you with an example to help design your own solution (if you have lots of time...): http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to play the uploaded videos as `video-on-demand (VOD)` you just need to put the resulting segments and the **m3u8** playlist in a web-accessible directory to be served via your web-server.

You can easily emulate a `live playlist` based on your complete playlist using node.js by serving an on-the-fly generated **m3u8**.

Eg:

1. For each new client session get the initial connection time
2. For each new GET request sent by the client calculate the current playing segment index using the difference between the initial time and the request time and the media segment durations in the complete **m3u8** playlist. This will be the last element in the playlist.
3. Find the previous `i - n` segments where `n` is your desired sliding-window size. Increase `n` if the current window size is less than three time the target duration. Use `i - n` as the `#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE` value.
4. Write the playlist containing the `n` resulting segments
5. Repeat 2-4 for each request for each individual session.

By managing the time offsets properly you can also time-shift etc. Keep the segments indexed by play time in something like `memcached` for performance's sake.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. You are a life saver, I was starting to pull my hair out lol.

Comment: So for clarification I need to store the time when the file goes live, from there wait for requests. When a request comes in I store that time and subtract the start time from that then divide that by the duration of the ts segments?

Comment: I chose to index the playlist file for the case when segments don't have the same duration. But that's the idea, you determine how much time has passed for the client and you search the segment that should play. Then you generate the playlist to include the previous `n` segments of the sliding-window. The client will request the playlist at an interval equal to the segment target duration if the playlist changed or one-half the target duration if the playlist didn't change since the last request. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-16#section-6.3.4

Comment: What if I write every new segment every 3 sec? I mean I record my live stream and translate it. How do I update my m3u8 at client side? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at building a video streaming platform, which is something significantly difficult to do (it is much more than simply piping a binary stream from a node server to a client, of that's what you were thinking of).

You are looking at using services that provide that capability, like Microsoft Azure Media Services. I understand Amazon AWS also has such a service, but you'll need to check it out, I have experience with Microsoft AMS only.

Indeed, such a service will allow to playback an HLS, MP4 fragmented, and MPEG-DASH formats to clients as a live event, even providing adaptive streaming capabilities for different bitrates/resolutions. You can see an example [HERE](http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html) and check if that is what you are looking for.